# VB.NET Application Deployment with SQL database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, setup-deployment

I have developed a VB.NET application with SQL database, now i want to package it with the database and deploy it on some other machine which does not have SQL installed.

Comment: Your question is either too broad or asks for an opinion. I suspect that's why you are getting the downvotes. I suggest you read the help on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could use InstallShield - that will allow you to create an installer which includes your program and allows you to install your SQL Server 2008 instance.